# freeing pwfx after waveOutOpen throws

Tags: winapi, waveout

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743866(v=vs.85).aspx):
"You can free this [pwfx] structure immediately after passing it to waveOutOpen."

But this code dosen't seem to agree:

```
pwfx=new WAVEFORMATEX;
pwfx->wFormatTag=WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
pwfx->nChannels=2;
pwfx->nSamplesPerSec=SPS;
pwfx->nAvgBytesPerSec=SPS*2;
pwfx->nBlockAlign=2;
pwfx->wBitsPerSample=8;
mmres=waveOutOpen(&ghwo,uDeviceID,pwfx,dwCallback,dwCallbackInstance,fdwOpen);
delete pwfx;
```

[image: screen picture with code & call stack]

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I can see in the code you provided is that you did not fully initialise the struct. You did not initialise `cbSize` which in this instance must be set to `0`.

Given that you are not allocating any extra data at the end of this struct, there's no need to allocate it in the heap.

It's entirely plausible that the problem lies in the other parameters that you pass to the function. We can't see any details of them, and therefore can't comment.

Comment: In that case I guess the problem will be in code we cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `new` or `delete` anything.  You can just do:

```
WAVEFORMATEX wfx = { };
wfx.wFormatTag=WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
...
mmres=waveOutOpen(&ghwo,uDeviceID,&wfx,dwCallback,dwCallbackInstance,fdwOpen);
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: I can, but that doesn't answer my question. Thanks anyway

Comment: Then, as @DavidHeffernan says, the problem must lie elsewhere.  Also, *please*, post text and not images.  Thanks.

Comment: The API can be used with additional data at the end of the struct, which is why the documentation describes freeing the struct. In that scenario it would be common to allocate on the heap. Of course that is not the scenario here.